# why after calling the method my kivymd app won't close?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivymd

i've tried using '''App.get_running_app().close()''' but with no results at all, I have read the documentation but have not found anything useful, can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `on_press=lambda x: MDApp.stop(self)` to your button if you are using python.
If you are using kv to do this then make a function,

```py
def close_app(self):
    MDApp.stop(self)
```

and add `on_press: root.close_app()` or `on_press: app.close_app()`to your kv button

Comment: ty but won't closing my window